# Display static dialog box as a part of chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently writing chrome extension, which should basically display 100x100 pixel dialog box in the bottom left corner on every opened page (it should be always on top).

I have currently two ideas:

1. Just embed this box element to the page's DOM (e.g. with iframe).
2. **Display some kind of popup, which is part of chrome extension tab but is not attached to the page's DOM (is it possible?)**

I prefer the second approach, since this box should stay there, during navigation and collect some data from the current page. However, I do not know if it is possible to display such a box without attaching it to the page's DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Extensions can have [page actions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) and [browser actions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), but otherwise aren't allowed to change Chrome's chrome. This is by design and won't be changed.